# Do 2nd Generation Managed Package name space dev org's expire?

Tags: salesforcedx, namespace

Say I'm developing a 2nd generation package (managed or unlocked) with a new namespace and I create a developer org and register the new namespace in it and link the namespace to my devhub. Do I need to login to this developer org periodically to prevent Salesforce from recycling the developer org and perhaps my package namespace?

Frankly I would like to toss the credentials and never think about this developer org again after I've defined the namespace.  Can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to login to this developer org periodically to prevent Salesforce from recycling the developer org and perhaps my package namespace?

No, orgs that own namespaces do not expire.

> Frankly I would like to toss the credentials and never think about this developer org again after I've defined the namespace. Can I do that?

Don't do this! You will need access to this org in the future to [link this namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_reg_namespace.htm) to any Dev Hubs you wish to use to build your package.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation David!   I didn't know that a namespace org could be associated with more than one devhub!   OK, I understand that I need to hold on to the packaging org credentials even though we're not doing any packaging there anymore.